# Npgsqlを用いてPostgreSQLにアクセスする際にCPU負荷が上がるとタイムアウトが発生する。

Tags: c#, postgresql

#### 質問

複数のアプリケーションが同じテーブルに登録、更新、参照を行う際に一つのアプリケーション(後述のアプリケーションC)の負荷によりCPU稼働率が100%となると稀にNpgsqlのコネクション処理で `npgsql.util.npgsqltimeout.check and get time left()` が発生します。

具体的には後述のアプリケーションBの以下のロジックのconnection.Open()にて発生します。
また、アプリケーションB、Cそれぞれで情報を取得する際に以下のロジックを用いています。
DBの設定は初期のままなのですが、設定のチューニングが問題なのかCPU負荷が原因で必ず発生するようならアプリケーションCの負荷を下げたほうが良いのかご助言いただけると助かります。

#### 実行環境

- Windows 10 もしくは Windows Server 2022
- PostgreSQL 15 各アプリケーションにより参照され、各アプリケーションと同じ環境上に構築(localhost接続)状態監視の結果をテーブルへ書き込んでいる。
- アプリケーションA(.Net Frameworkのコンソールアプリケーション、C#で記述)
- アプリケーションB、C(.Net FrameworkのWindowsフォームアプリケーション、C#で記述)

#### 利用状況

- アプリケーションA(CPU使用率30%)・・・0.5秒おきにセンサーの情報を確認し、変化があった際にDBにInsertもしくはUpdate
- アプリケーションB(CPU使用率5%)・・・10秒おきに機器情報やテーブルの情報を参照し、画面に表示する。
- アプリケーションC(CPU使用率65%)・・・ユーザーが任意に実行し、テーブルの情報を外部にファイル出力する。

#### コード

```
public List<LogdataDto> selectLogData()
{
    try
    {
        ConnectDB con = new ConnectDB();
        List<LogdataDto> result = new List<LogdataDto>();
        
        // コマンド生成
        string sql = "select * from logtable";
        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = con.getConnection())
        {
            using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
            
                // 接続開始
                connection.Open();

                // SELECT文の実行
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        LogdataDto temp = new LogdataDto();
                        temp.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                        temp.occurreddt = DateTime.Parse(reader["occurreddt"].ToString());
                        temp.status = reader["status"].ToString();
                        result.Add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
 public NpgsqlConnection getConnection()
 {
     try
     {
         DBInfo db = Config.GetDBInfo();
         string con = $"Server={db.ip};Port={db.port};Username={db.id};Password={db.pass};Database={db.dbname}";
         return new NpgsqlConnection(con);
     }
     catch(Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }
 }
```

Comment: アプリケーションＢの接続文字列で ConnectionLifeTime を指定し、既定値の 15 秒をゼロ(無制限)にしたらどうなりますか？

Answer (score 1):

各種タイムアウトを長めに設定する事は可能でしょうが、
まずCPU使用率を下げる方法を調査してみた方がいい気がします。

> アプリケーションC(CPU使用率65%)・・・ユーザーが任意に実行し、テーブルの情報を外部にファイル出力する。

とありますが、出力に全力でループ回すとCPUずっと使いっぱなしになりそうな気がするので、〇件出力したら [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=net-8.0) 挟むとかするとマシになりそうな気がしますが。
（件数は処理時間との兼ね合いで適当に調整してみてください）

Answer (score 1):

質問文の内容(※)から予想するに、アプリケーション側でタイムアウトしていると予想します。

(※)CPU使用率が高い際まれに発生、接続失敗、接続パラメータはデフォルト。

Npgsqlの接続パラメータのドキュメント([Timeouts and Keepalive](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#timeouts-and-keepalive))では、パラメータ「`Timeout`」デフォルト「15」秒とあるので、これを延ばすことで、事象が解消できるかもしれません。

Comment: コネクションプールのパラメータは「`Pooling`」が`true`なのでデフォルト有効、「`Connection Lifetime`」が`0(disable)`なので無期限生存、のようなので、チューニングしなくてもよいように見えました。